# jQuery image swap on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you hover over the Dharma arrow image in my sample link, it's meant to replace the bunny picture with the same you're hovering.

I was doing it [here at jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/3ehnB/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose the correct framework within jsfiddle... you have mootools selected. Your code works fine.

You can also change back on rollout...

```
    var switchback
$("#myImage-hover").hover( function() {
        switchback = $('#myImage').attr("src");
        $('#myImage').attr("src", "http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090830130818/lostpedia/images/thumb/2/2e/The_Arrow_logo.svg/128px-The_Arrow_logo.svg.png");

    }, function() {

        $('#myImage').attr("src", switchback);
        switchback = ""
});
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I was just typing in the rollout as you answered, the main question was "Why isn't this working?" and yeah.. I should pay more attention to library selecting *embarrassed*...

Comment: I shouldn't use static sources, for example you could store the original source and use it later when mouseout.

Answer (score 2):

In jsFiddle, you must define the jQuery library

http://jsfiddle.net/3ehnB/2/

Comment: :D I knew it was something like that! Thanks! :D